# Applying PySpark dropDuplicates method messes up the sorting of the data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, drop-duplicates

I'm not sure why this is the behaviour, but when I apply `dropDuplicates` to a sorted data frame, the sorting order is disrupted. See the following two tables in comparison.

The following table is the output of `sorted_df.show()`, in which the sorting is in order.

```
+----------+-----------+
|sorted_col|another_col|
+----------+-----------+
|         1|          1|
|         8|          5|
|        15|          1|
|        19|          9|
|        20|          7|
|        27|          9|
|        67|          8|
|        91|          9|
|        91|          7|
|        91|          1|
+----------+-----------+
```

The following table is the output of `sorted_df.dropDuplicates().show()`, and the sorting is not right anymore, even though it's the same data frame.

```
+----------+-----------+
|sorted_col|another_col|
+----------+-----------+
|        27|          9|
|        67|          8|
|        15|          1|
|        91|          7|
|         1|          1|
|        91|          1|
|         8|          5|
|        91|          9|
|        20|          7|
|        19|          9|
+----------+-----------+
```

Can someone explain why this behaviour persists and how can I keep the same sorting order with `dropDuplicates` applied?

Apache Spark version 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropDuplicates` involves a `shuffle`. Ordering is therefore disrupted.